# Разделение логов по названиям логгеров в Django/Python (logging)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, логирование

Время суток доброе. Чтобы не искать по длинному файлу вывод одного модуля, хочу сделать логирование в специальный файл, название которого будет соответствовать названию логгера.

Попытки не привели ни к чему хорошему.
Наткнулся на TimeRotatedFileHadler, это что то похожее на то, что мне требуется. Но если дата и время доступны из любой точки приложения, то как получить названия логера, для которого используется обработчик?

В общем, мне нужно, чтобы логгер `django` писал в `django.log`, а `the_django_logger` писал в `the_django_logger.log` и тд, кол-во неограниченно. Конечно всегда есть вариант с копипастом, но при 100500 различных функционалов такое рефакторить будет проблематично